# C# Broadcast enviroment variable change to notify bat script?

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a C# console application that modifies an environment variable

```
 RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Environment", true);
 key.SetValue("BMKTARGET", targetLocation.Path, RegistryValueKind.String);
```

The problem is that after running it in cmd, I have to close cmd and restart cmd to recognize the change.... since cmd needs to be told that it is modified, so I tried to run this code I found online:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool SendMessageTimeout(
  IntPtr hWnd,
  int Msg,
  int wParam,
  string lParam,
  int fuFlags,
  int uTimeout,
  out int lpdwResult
);

public const int HWND_BROADCAST = 0xffff;
public const int WM_SETTINGCHANGE = 0x001A;
public const int SMTO_NORMAL = 0x0000;
public const int SMTO_BLOCK = 0x0001;
public const int SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = 0x0002;
public const int SMTO_NOTIMEOUTIFNOTHUNG = 0x0008;
//Run this function after modification 
static void BroadcastEnvironment()
{
    int result;
    SendMessageTimeout((IntPtr)HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, "Environment",
      SMTO_BLOCK | SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG | SMTO_NOTIMEOUTIFNOTHUNG, 5000, out result);
}
```

Somehow it still doesn't work, how can I fix this?

**Note:**

I'm trying to pass information to a `.bat` script that is running this exe... if there is a better way to do this, I'll be happy with that answer.

**PS**

someone in the comments made what looks to be a good suggestion, but without sufficient information to test it, If some one could elaborate that would be appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think a console application such as cmd.exe has a thread running a `WindowProc`? It doesn't. Explorer does, which is why restarting cmd.exe picks up the changes.

Comment: [Handling Messages in Console Apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163417.aspx)

Comment: @eryksun I don't want a restart, that would be really annoying considering what this does..... I don't see why I can't just "update" cmd.exe...? BTW, the cod I found claims to work on cmd.exe, I didn't write it....

Comment: @eryksun I believe you there, however creating a new console window is not an option.....

Comment: @eryksun Oh, okay, I shall have to try it... it would be great if you could write it up as an answer so if it works I can mark it as accepted... I can wait for my application to close. Also include how my .bat file can wait (if it doesn't already) for the application to finish running

Comment: @user3765372: what exactly does the batch file do?  Can it's functionality be transferred to the console app?

Comment: Did someone remove a bunch of comments....?

Comment: @user3765372: apparently.

Answer (score 1):

No need for all that registry mucking about.

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("BMKTARGET", targetLocation.Path,
                                   EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
```

and

```
var value = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BMKTARGET",
                                               EnvironmentVariableTarget.User)
```

additionally, this [batch script](https://gist.github.com/grawity/1790098) posted by [@grawity](https://superuser.com/users/1686/grawity) on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/388399/125282) may be of some utility to you.

[@eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun) says that instead of the script all you need is this one-liner for your batch file:

```
for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('reg query HKCU\Environment /v BMKTARGET') do set "BMKTARGET=%%b"
```

Comment: Thank you @eryksun.  `GetEnvironmentVariable` was simply trying to show the inverse of setting it - for completeness.  I appreciate the additional batch one-liner.

Comment: The problem is I'm trying to pass data out of my script to the batch file...... I'm not trying to set it in the batch file...

Comment: Suggested command gives output: `%%a was unexpected at this time.`